# How to fix: "text isn't centered in form fields" on iOS devices (Elementor)

Tags: ios, css, forms, elementor

*My problem*

I have embedded a Memberpress form inside my Wordpress page (designed with Elementor), but when trying to fill out the form on iOS devices, the text inside the field is not centered. I can only see the top of the text.

The problem doesn't seem to appear on other operating systems, and it doesn't happen on desktops.

Have a look at a screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg0ai.jpg

---

*What I have tried to do*

I have tried to embed some custom CSS with no effect. I might not be getting the syntax right as I am fairly new to this - and to the "Custom CSS" function of Elementor.

```
{-webkit-user-select:text;}
```

And also:

```
<meta name="viewport": 
content="height=device-height; 
width=device-width initial scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, 
user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi"}>
```

Comment: when you added the viewport did you also use vw for the width and vh for the height?

Comment: No I literally added the text as you see it there. 

I am not good at all with CSS- when I entered the code in Elementor, an error was flagged: "Expected COLON at line 1, column 16"

selector {meta name="viewport": 
content="height=device-height; 
width=device-width initial scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, 
user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi"}>